# Handling the key collision in Hashmap

Tags: java, collections, hashtable

The [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.put%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object%29) I found for Hashmap's `put(K key, V value)`. This method replaces the value if collision occured, it doesn't add the `Entry` to the LinkedList of the bucket.
What I am missing here?

Comment: I think you're mixing up collision (same hash code) with equals (actually equivalent).

Comment: May be. I wanted to see how does java handles collision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think? The relevant lines are as follows:

Calculate index in internal table:

```
390 int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
```

Iterate over the linked list at `table[i]` and search if the key is already contained:

```
391 for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
392     Object k;
393     if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
```

Key is already contained => replace value...

```
394         V oldValue = e.value;
395         e.value = value;
396         e.recordAccess(this);
```

...and return old value

```
397         return oldValue;
398     }
```

otherwise continue the loop

```
399 }
```

We're at the end of the linked list and we haven't found the key yet, so it's not already contained. So let's add a new entry:

```
402 addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
```

Comment: Line `394-396` is my problem. Why is it replacing the old value?

Comment: See specification of Map#put: "(...)If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.(...). This is not 'collision', as others already stated in their answers. Collision occure if two keys have the same hash code but are NOT equal. In that case replacement doesn't happen! (see line 402).

Comment: If you need to hold multiple values per key, consider either using a List as value or a third party library that provides a MultiMap (e.g. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't missing a thing. The general contract for Java's `Map`s is to have a single value per key.
If you want to hold multiple values per key, you'd have to use something like [Apache Commons' MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html), or implement something similar on your own by having a `Map<K, List<V>>`.

Comment: Are you saying that Java HashMap does not handles collision scenario. It just replaces the value. Is it so?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav note that the internal linkedlist is for all the keys **with the same hashcode** - not for equal keys (in which case, the value would be replaced, as noted)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same key several times in an `HashMap`. That is why the value gets replaced rather than just creating a new  `Map.Entry<K,V>`